# @permission_classes((IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)) allowing anonymous user to post data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

I have added @permission_classes((IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)) annotation on my view n on calling post without auth details it is allowing to post data?

```
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,))
@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def my_view(request):
    # code for post and get
```

Comment: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#function-based-views

Comment: you missed this @authentication_classes(...) i think

Answer (score 1):

You missed this:

```
@authentication_classes(...)
```